# why my iterator and pointer not giving the same address?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I tried `begin` iterator and then I used the pointer to point the first element of the vector. Then I print the addresses of them and they were `0x6efed8 0x6efedc`.

I have read that iterator are like abstraction of pointers. They both are refering to same element so I thought that there result will be same.

**Why they are different ?**

If there is problem in code then please figure that out as well.

```
 vector<int> data{10,20,30};
    auto i = data.begin();
    auto* j = &data;
    cout << &i << " " << j << endl;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you were expecting these two things to be at the same address?  The address of `data` and the address of an iterator that is iterating `data`?

Comment: @DrewDormann i have read that iterator are like abstraction of pointers. They both are referring to same element so I thought that there result will be same. Sorry if I waste your time.

Comment: @RivenCallahan what you have read is accurate.  They refer to the same element, but the address of one is not the other.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @DrewDormann the thing that was clicking was that the element 10 will be somewhere in the memory having a particular address so I just wanted to see that pointer to initial element if vector and begin iterator should be same.

Comment: @RivenCallahan what i didnt adress in the answer is that `&data` is not the first element, that would be `&data[0]`, however the adresses are still different

Comment: @user463035818 yes, I know I have to use subscript operator for that. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets rewrite your code just a bit:

```
struct foo { 
    int bar() { return 1; }
};

int main() {
    foo data;
    auto i = data.bar();
    auto* j = &data;
    std::cout << &i << " " << j;
}
```

`i` is a copy of whatever `data.bar()` returned. It is a different object, of different type, stored at a different memory adress. (...and nothing of that changes if you replace `foo` with `std::vector<int>`)

PS: note that `&data` is not a pointer to the first element, that would be `&data[0]`, which is yet another adress, because the first element is different from the vector itself or from an iterator to the first element.

Comment: Thank you sir. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Walter I dont understand what "one error" or what other errors you refer to. After fixing the includes there is no error in OPs code: https://wandbox.org/permlink/2AA2tGPBDVRgMitE

Comment: @Walter maybe `&data` vs `&data[0]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
 vector<int> data{10,20,30};
 auto i = data.begin();
```

the `begin()`  funtion returns an iterator referring to the first data element of the vector - i.e. the element containing `10`

while:

```
 auto* j = &data;
```

gives you a pointer to the vector itself, not to any specific element.

These are two completely different things; the types of `i` and `j` are completely different and unrelated.